# Include graphics command doesn't work. Can you help me?

Tags: includegraphics, turkish

Include graphics command doesn't work. Can you help me? 
I am using latex online editor and I write `\includegraphics[width=0.9 \linewidth]{graph.png}` as command but `width=0.9 \linewidth` part doesnt work and the latex doesn't scale the image.

Note: I used turkish language pack

Comment: babel turkish makes = active (not clear why really) you can use the babel command to turn off the = shorthand

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  It is dishonest to use unapproved magic crystal ball.  `:)`